Boolean modifier union turning texture black in render view
In other viewports material appears normal. It is black only in render. I use Cycles render.
In other render modes it is normal too.

Does someone know what the issue is?

Please share your Blend file so that we can see what is going on.  You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the full link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

Check if normals are inverted or if you have overlapping geometry(overlapping faces or vertices). Next would be checking the materials. Full specific answer would require more info like the file shared or at least some screenshots with all UI visible.
